# is there a way to not have view for an action in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In rails + jQuery I am trying to make a get request back to the server when an option in the dropdown box is changed. I use the following jquery code:

```
$("#product_prod_name").change(function(){
    $.get("/page/volume_or_quant", "id="+$(this).val(), function(result) {
        alert(result)
    })
})
```

now this is giving an error: `Missing template pages/volume_or_quant.erb in view path app/views`

As you can see...i have no need to create a view. I just want some response back from my action. My action looks like below:

```
def volume_or_quant
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.volume     
end
```

What is the best thing to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def volume_or_quant
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    render :text => product.volume      
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def volume_or_quant
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.volume    

    # tell rails to ignore the view
    render :layout => false
end
```

Should do the trick for you.

Comment: This only ignores the layout, but requires a view nevertheless.